# Azure Bot Service app doesn't load build options after changing subscription

Tags: azure, botframework, azureportal, azure-bot-service

I have a Bot App Service in the Azure Portal. I had it in a subscription under a resource group called "pnibot", then I had to move it to another subscription, now under a resource group called "PNI". The app itself is working properly.
My problem is that when I click the resource to open it and get the build options (the view that lets you open the code editor or download the source code), I get this error:

"The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/pnibot' under resource group 'pnibot' was not found."

As I said the bot works properly, and I can open the other tabs with no problem (Channels, Analytics, Settings), but I need to be constantly opening this view to work on the code and sometimes download it, so this is a tedious issue. Can anyone help?